# Sharing vm machine between applications

Tags: google-app-engine, jenkins, google-compute-engine

I have production GAE application - **myapp**. I've created also second app - **myapp-staging** to have separate, staging environment.

In **myapp** I've created Jenkins machine to get Build pipeline.

It's easy to run test and deploy jobs on the same app. But there is a problem with deploy version from Jenkins VM on **myapp** to **myapp-staging**. I got unknown application (or similar) error while *gcloud preview deploy*.

Is it possible to give access from VM on one application to another one? Especially for *gcloud* command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Jenkins instance is using a service account which is enabled as **myapp** admin but has no access to **myapp-staging** . You'll have to either:

1) Setup your original Jenkins with a second service account with admin rights to **myapp-staging**

2) Setup a second Jenkins instance and trigger the build of the staging version when the first one is complete.

Comment: many thanks :) I cannot find a place, where I can add permission. Now with added service account from *myapp*, it works. And first point is perfectly ok for me. I would like one Jenkins for all build pipeline, without delegating jobs between instances.